Progress bar updating on different thread
I wrote a program on C# Windows Forms to save files on MATLAB.
The function of saving data on MATLAB takes too long to run, so I decide to use progress bars to show user how long will take to complete process.
I attach my code, It runs OK in some cases, but in some other cases I gets the error:

System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Probable I/O race condition detected while copying memory. The I/O package is not thread safe by default. In multithreaded applications, a stream must be accessed in a thread-safe way, such as a thread-safe wrapper returned by TextReader's or TextWriter's Synchronized methods. This also applies to classes like StreamWriter and StreamReader.'

I want to have the main function on the main thread, while having progress bar updates on another thread, and of course I want files to be stored one by one, and progress bar filling progresses one by one.
Indeed I want to avoid multi threading since the whole program is written in single thread manner, just have one other thread to update each progress bar value. Bellow is my code. I'm glad to have your great helps.
public class SaveToMatlab
{
    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();

        private void BtnSaveToMatlab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ResetProgressBars();
            if (!backgroundWorker.IsBusy)
            {
                backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }


        private void BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Count; i++)
            {
                var flp = tableLayoutPanel.Controls[i] as FlowLayoutPanel;
                if (flp != null && flp.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Any(x => x.Checked))
                {
                    progressBar = flp.Controls.OfType<ProgressBar>().FirstOrDefault();
                    if (progressBar != null)
                    {
                        var directory = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "MatlabOutput");
                        fileList[i].SaveLogToMatWorkSpace(Path.Combine(directory, $"matlab_{fileList[i].GetIdentifier()}.mat"), backgroundWorker);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar.Value = progressBar.Value + e.ProgressPercentage > 100 ? 100 : progressBar.Value + e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        private void BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Operation was canceled.");
            }
            else if (e.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred: " + e.Error.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Operation completed successfully.");
            }
        }
    }


public class OtherClass
{
    public void SaveLogToMatWorkSpace(string fileName, BackgroundWorker worker)
    {
            if (indices.Count > 0)
            {
                double increment = 100 / (double)(indices.Count - 1);

                for (int i = 0; i < indices.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (indices[i].Count > 0)
                    {
                        //... My code to save in MATLAB...
                    }

                    int progress = (int)Math.Ceiling(increment);

                    worker.ReportProgress(progress);
                }

                new MatFileWriter(fileName, mlList, true);
            }
        }
}


If your slow method is async you would simply write a loop:
public async Task DoWork(){
    foreach(var file in filelist){
        await file.SaveLogToMatWorkSpace(...);
        UpdateProgressBar();
    }
}

If SaveLogToMatWorkSpace does negligible work on the UI thread this should keep the UI responsive.
If the slow method is not async you do not really have an option, you need to use another thread. The UI thread can only do one thing at a time, and if it is running a slow method it cannot react to user input or draw itself, resulting in the "application have stopped responding error".
One way to avoid most of the dangers of multi threading is to show a modal dialog while the background thread is processing. This helps prevent running any of your code concurrently, and therefore helps avoid many threading issues, while still allowing the UI to draw itself and process input. This might look something like:
public async void OnButtonClick()
{
    var progress = new Progress<int>();
    var progressWindow = new MyProgressWindow(progress);
    var task = StartWork(progressWindow, progress);
// ShowDialogwill prevent the user from interacting with anything other than the ProgressWindow.
    progressWindow.ShowDialog(); 
    try
    {
        var result = await task;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // handle errors
    }

}

public async Task<MyResult> StartWork(Window window, IProgress<int> progress)
{
    var result = await Task.Run(() => DoWork(progress));
   // Automatically close the progress window when the work is done
   // Use `async/await` to continue on the UI thread once DoWork has completed
    window.Close(); 
    return result;
}

public MyResult DoWork(IProgress<int> progress)
{
    // Do actual work on a background thread
    // use progress.Report(i); to report progress 
}

MyProgressWindow would be a simple window containing a progress bar, and not much more. Don't forget to disable the close buttons on the window, setting the owner, etc. Listen to the progress.ProgressChanged event to update the progress bar.
You could do the same without a modal dialog, but you either need to make sure anything the user can do is safe while DoWork is in progress, or disable any unsafe actions. So showing a modal dialog is usually much simpler.
The progress class is thread safe, and explicitly designed for cases like this, but you cannot access any other part of the UI in DoWork. Extract any needed information in StartWork, and pass them as parameters to DoWork.
You could also consider adding a cancel button, See CancellationTokenSource.
